# About the implementation of the iterator function of Dart's List class

Tags: flutter, dart

I am investigating Iterable and iterator of Dart (Flutter).

I got a rough idea of the rough mechanism of Iterable, iterator, etc.

Looking at the source code for the List type, which is a typical type of Iterable,

↓ First, the List  class implements the abstract class EfficientLengthIterable  class.

There is no description about the iterator property in the List  class.
I can't find any code that initializes the iterator property in the constructor.

```
//list.dart
abstract class List<E> implements EfficientLengthIterable<E> {
   ...
```

---

The superclass of the EfficientLengthIterable  class is the Iterable  class.

EfficientLengthIterable  itself has no implementation code for the iterator property.

(The ListIterable  class is defined a little below, and the ListIterable class has the iterator property initialization code.

However, I can't find any code that the List  class inherits from ListIterable . )

```
//internal/iterable.dart
abstract class EfficientLengthIterable<T> extends Iterable<T> {
  const EfficientLengthIterable();
  int get length;
}

abstract class ListIterable<E> extends EfficientLengthIterable<E> {
   ...
```

---

The iterator property of the Iterable  class is declared, but it is only declared and not initialized. (Because it's an abstract class, I think it's normal.)

```
//core/iterable.dart
abstract class Iterable<E> {
   ...
   Iterator<E> get iterator;
   ...
```

At a glance, it looks like this, and in this case, the iterator property of the instance of the List  class is not initialized, so I feel that it will be null.

I don't think it's possible to iterate the list,
In fact (as a matter of course) it can iterate normally.

Under the definition of the EfficientLengthIterable class,

ListIterable class

ListIterator class

there is a definition such as.
And if the List class inherits the ListIterable class, I think there is no contradiction.

Even if I look at the name of class, it seems like it will be inherited.
But I can't find any code that shows such a relationship.

If I look at it normally, the class hierarchy is

Superclass ← Iterable ← EfficientLengthIterable ← List ← Subclass

It only looks like.
(Although List is not a subclass of EfficientLengthIterable, because implements are used.)

In the above class hierarchy, List cannot inherit the members of ListIterable (iterator property initialized by ListIterator instance), isn't it?

Is there code somewhere else that shows the relationship between the List  and ListIterable  classes?

Or does this code properly initialize the iterator property of an instance of the List class?

Comment: Did you find an explanation for this? Even in the latest version, I cannot see any connection between `List` and `ListIterable`.